# Honda Fit's iPod car plug: what cable is this?

Tags: ipod, car-integration

My car, a Japanese Honda Fit, has a radio with a plug marked **iPod** on the cover but I have no idea what type of cable/plug I must use to connect it with my iPod.

Can anyone tell based on the picture? the right port

[image: Car radio, iPod plug]

Comment: i tried again and again but its all in Japanese so i couldnt..

Comment: i couldnt find one. this cars comes as used cars from Japan so everything is in Japanese. not just the manual

Comment: Do you have a name of that adapter cable? maybe i can order one

Comment: As this is an issue with a Honda vehicle not really an Apple issue I'd suggest you go to a Honda Dealership to resolve your Honda vehicle issue.

Comment: If I were to guess, I would say this is a Honda-specific form of Apple's 30-pin dock connector. Is suggest posting in other forums like [/r/honda]:(reddit.com/r/homda), as you'll be more likely to come across someone who's had similar problems.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for this kind of cable/adapter : 
[image]

[on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009L4NY8Q)

---

Previous answer :

The Left AUX Jack. It's for a "simple" jack 3.5 cable.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i meant the right port.

Comment: I updated my answer !

Comment: thank you Matthieu. this seams an adapter to be connected to the back ports of the radio. for the frond i only need an adapter. thanks again :)